# Using HL7 message to insert data in my SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hl7, mirth

I'm using mirth for sending and receiving HL7 message.

Is it possible to insert custom data (char datatype) in my SQL Server database by picking up a HL7 message (file type) mapping it with my columns of my database using transformer and inserting to my database.

And is there any option of generating status in a outbound HL7 message in mirth ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a destination connector type of Database Writer to write data from the input HL7 message to your database.

You can use a second destination connector to generate an output HL7 message based on the input.

You mentioned status -- can you be more explicit?  What status, from the database call or something else?

You could add a ZZZ segment to the outbound message to hold whatever status information you need to send.

EDIT:
Here's how to use javascript to add a ZZZ segment.

```
createSegment('ZZZ', msg);
msg['ZZZ']['ZZZ.1']['ZZZ.1.1'] = "This is ZZZ.1"; // These are a pain to type!
msg['ZZZ']['ZZZ.2']['ZZZ.2.1'] = "Field ZZZ.2 can contain whatever you want";
msg['ZZZ']['ZZZ.3']['ZZZ.3.1'] = "such as date, time, results of database update";
```

Comment: thanks for help, now data is getting inserted properly...and one more thing, but do i have to create Z segments manually in my HL7 message ?? i mean, i have modify the message in terms of including the z segments??

Comment: See my edit above.  I added code for creating the ZZZ segment.  Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The UltraPort MS SQL Schema Engine does exactly what you're looking for. That's all that it does, it's very fast and very good at it, and has free fully functional trial. It sets up in literally minutes and they've got really good customer service. If you call in they'll walk you through a 10-15 minute example of importing HL7 messages (and actually encourage you to use your own HL7 data if you have any). 10-15 minutes will answer 90% of any questions you might ever have and it includes downloading and installing the software.

Home Page: http://www.hermetechnz.com/EasyHL7/prod_sql.asp
Online Help: http://www.hermetechnz.com/Documentation/UltraPort/MSSQL/index.html

It stores both the unparsed HL7 message as well as breaking it into parsed data tables as well as (optionally) storing the unparsed SEGMENTS as individual rows.

Also, you can easily customize the HL7 Version definitions to include "Z" segments or custom datatypes used by specific vendors.

Hope this helps.